Mindcrime feat. Spielberg

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. City in North Macedonia – almost Greekish – after vacation time...? I Remember Now! (2,5)
5. Fine! The setter's got a short break to take! (4)
7. Literary cuckold Charles, as young man, got very hardcore? (6)
11. Jaws is sent regularly to get 007? (5)
12. Classic gear that gets in Anarchy X (3,5,6)
14. Number one Mexican food vendor's tip after Revolution Calling (8)
16. In the afternoon, flippin' Operation: Mindcrime set played without either side in collaboration (4,8)
17. Speak with digits, coming after second-rate klutz (13)
20. Open Office Writer is behind Urban document? (7)
22. Heard was heard in a 2022 one? That's no big deal, ignoring even characters from Kiev (5)
24. Female care, with L'Oréal, out at sea is a way of Spreading the Disease (5-4,5)
29. Where The Mission control is attracted to entertaining America (7)
32. Suite Sister Mary, essentially a goddess (5)
33. Site of The Needle Lies, oddly, to the east of failed state (7)
34. Twice rejecting Electric Requiem's line, then scrambling, leads to submission (14)
37. Around one for every heist (5)
38. Revolutionary green robes at last adopted by, as they say in Munich, the bishopric (7)
40. State Breaking the Silence in accepting LGBT, finally (13)
43. Criminal in essence stating I Don't Believe in Love, ultimately, during online feed shows remorse (12)
46. In Spooner's words, hit slammer to escape Waiting for 22 across (4,4)
50. Nighttime flyer terrorised the Arab Resistance, with chief of operations held in My Empty Room (6,8)
52. Many times, born around this time last decade? (5)
53. I just remembered this Axis leader who specialised in guerrilla warfare in spirit (6)
54. Driver in Hollywood's Amistad production: Is time running out? (4)
55. Those behind Eyes of a Stranger in addiction support group: A bit scary and concerning! (2,3,2)
Down
1. Uncovered: Bold and savvy monarch from Norway (4,1)
2. Alternative to brilliant wine mixed with other substances (4,3)
3. 10-4 after first part of game – noted Yugoslav is coming from behind (3,2)
4. Precisely, without a little one (3)
5. Feel agitation about afro trimmed by The Extra-Terrestrial (4)
6. Rambling and cycling? Always, chief! Endlessly! (7)
7. Military wake-up caller to annoy foremost members in legion (5)
8. Hostility against ZZ Top, for example in Land of Lincoln? (7)
9. Teacher of king (and King!) making an appearance in Artificial Intelligence (5)
10. Dishes of tapas prepared with dash of salt (6)
13. Nothing on Monday for Russian black berets (4, abbr.)
15. From oaf: "If roof evens out...?" (3,2)
17. Clumsy kid, having itch, scratched head (6)
18. Sleek swimmer Bruce who's often shown shirtless from behind (3)
19. Yankees' base, located in US state that touches the Atlantic Ocean, for short (3, abbr.)
20. Actor Christian's making a lot of hay? (5)
21. Participants in group: It's to provide time for necessary maintenance (3,4)
23. Minute robotic components yet to be delivered (2,5)
25. Secure entrance for lecturer at church (5)
26. If it wasn't for The Terminal, exceptional format for compressed files (3, abbr.)
27. Made out excessively fertile cells (3)
28. The lively capital from Iran? (6)
30. It's spoken by many in Ghana – one in two – for naught? (3)
31. Unorthodox, mostly equine nickname which omits an initial "Mo" (5)
32. According to his family members, dictator in India being accompanied by European princess (3)
35. Old English character's initially all right to leave our home (3)
36. Coming up: You have a sit-down with the Finnish Flash (5)
37. AC/DC cover not included on studio's initial records (3, abbr.)
38. Richard watched Jurassic Park, finally; I joined partway through (4)
39. Unpredictable son of President Trump catches traitor (7)
40. Those with little interest in others: Check it out, old hat with mostly new clothes in restaurants! (6)
41. Made attempts to ogle; in the end decided to grab butt from behind (7)
42. He no longer seeks parts as someone engaged in extortion (7)
44. Shows a lack of necessities (5)
45. Every now and then, stars perform very well, making splash (5)
47. Evidence described by company department: Female couple in Hook up (5)
48. Thoroughfares for passenger vehicles lacking parking (5)
49. Popular choice of where to meet in The Post-covid era is where to see caged beasts and men (4)
51. Marcellus's girlfriend is nowhere to be found (3)

Completed grid:

 

Across clues:

 1. City in North Macedonia – almost Greekish – after vacation time...? I Remember Now! (2,5) - OH RIGHT - OHRI(-d) + G_H + T
 5. Fine! The setter's got a short break to take! (4) - FIVE - F + I'VE
 7. Literary cuckold Charles, as young man, got very hardcore? (6) - BOVARY - BOY got V + _AR_
 11. Jaws is sent regularly to get 007? (5) - ASSET - _A_S _S _E_T
 12. Classic gear that gets in Anarchy X (3,5,6) - THE GREAT GATSBY - GEARTHATGETS* + BY
 14. Number one Mexican food vendor's tip after Revolution Calling (8) - VOCATION - (NO. + I + TACO + V_)<
 16. In the afternoon, flippin' Operation: Mindcrime set played without either side in collaboration (4,8) - POST MERIDIEM - <OP + MI(-_n)D(-c_)RIMESET
 17. Speak with digits, coming after second-rate klutz (13) - BUTTERFINGERS - UTTER + FINGERS coming after B
 20. Open Office Writer is behind Urban document? (7) - BULLPEN - PEN behind BULL
 22. Heard was heard in a 2022 one? That's no big deal, ignoring even characters from Kiev (5) - TRIAL - TR(-_i_v)IAL
 24. Female care, with L'Oréal, out at sea is a way of Spreading the Disease (5-4,5) - FECAL-ORAL ROUTE - F + CARELOREALOUT*
 29. Where The Mission control is attracted to entertaining America (7) - HOUSTON - HOT ON entertaining US
 32. Suite Sister Mary, essentially a goddess (5) - ISTAR - _I_ _ST_ _AR_
 33. Site of The Needle Lies, oddly, to the east of failed state (7) - SEATTLE - L_E_ to the east of STATE*
 34. Twice rejecting Electric Requiem's line, then scrambling, leads to submission (14) - RELINQUISHMENT - R(-e)QUI(-e)MSLINETHEN*
 37. Around one for every heist (5) - CAPER - C. + A + PER
 38. Revolutionary green robes at last adopted by, as they say in Munich, the bishopric (7) - DIOCESE - ECO< + _S adopted by DIE
 40. State Breaking the Silence in accepting LGBT, finally (13) - LIECHTENSTEIN - THESILENCEIN* accepting _T
 43. Criminal in essence stating I Don't Believe in Love, ultimately, during online feed shows remorse (12) - CONTRITENESS - CON + _T_ + (I _T _E _N _E during RSS)
 46. In Spooner's words, hit slammer to escape Waiting for [TRIAL] (4,4) - JUMP BAIL - Spoonerism of "bump jail"
 50. Nighttime flyer terrorised the Arab Resistance, with chief of operations held in My Empty Room (6,8) - BERTHA ARMYWORM - THEARAB* + R + (W/ + O_ held in MY R_M)
 52. Many times, born around this time last decade? (5) - OFTEN - def + cdef (approximately ten years old)
 53. I just remembered this Axis leader who specialised in guerrilla warfare in spirit (6) - PSYCHE - P.S. + Y + CHE
 54. Driver in Hollywood's Amistad production: Is time running out? (4) - ADAM - AM(-is -t)AD*
 55. Those behind Eyes of a Stranger in addiction support group: A bit scary and concerning! (2,3,2) - AS FAR AS - _S _F _A _R in AA + S_

Down clues:

 1. Uncovered: Bold and savvy monarch from Norway (4,1) - OLAV V - _OL_ _AVV_
 2. Alternative to brilliant wine mixed with other substances (4,3) - ROSE CUT - ROSÉ + CUT
 3. 10-4 after first part of game – noted Yugoslav is coming from behind (3,2) - GOT IT - G_ + TITO<
 4. Precisely, without a little one (3) - TOT - TO (-a) T
 5. Feel agitation about afro trimmed by The Extra-Terrestrial (4) - FRET - _FR_ + ET
 6. Rambling and cycling? Always, chief! Endlessly! (7) - VERBOSE - (e->)VER BOS_(->E)
 7. Military wake-up caller to annoy foremost members in legion (5) - BUGLE - BUG + LE_
 8. Hostility against ZZ Top, for example in Land of Lincoln? (7) - VITRIOL - V. + TRIO in IL
 9. Teacher of king (and King!) making an appearance in Artificial Intelligence (5) - RABBI - R + B.B. making an appearance in AI
 10. Dishes of tapas prepared with dash of salt (6) - PASTAS - TAPAS* + S_
 13. Nothing on Monday for Russian black berets (4, abbr.) - OMON - 0 + MON.
 15. From oaf: "If roof evens out...?" (3,2) - OFF OF - O_F _F _O_F
 17. Clumsy kid, having itch, scratched head (6) - BOTCHY - BOY having _TCH
 18. Sleek swimmer Bruce who's often shown shirtless from behind (3) - EEL - LEE<
 19. Yankees' base, located in US state that touches the Atlantic Ocean, for short (3, abbr.) - NYC - Y_ located in NC &lit!
 20. Actor Christian's making a lot of hay? (5) - BALES - ddef (BALE'S)
 21. Participants in group: It's to provide time for necessary maintenance (3,4) - PIT STOP - _P IT'S TO P_
 23. Minute robotic components yet to be delivered (2,5) - IN UTERO - _INUTE RO_
 25. Secure entrance for lecturer at church (5) - LATCH - L_ + AT + CH.
 26. If it wasn't for The Terminal, exceptional format for compressed files (3, abbr.) - RAR - RAR(-_e)
 27. Made out excessively fertile cells (3) - OVA - "over"
 28. The lively capital from Iran? (6) - TEHRAN - THE* + (-i)RAN &lit!
 30. It's spoken by many in Ghana – one in two – for naught? (3) - TWI - TW(o->I)
 31. Unorthodox, mostly equine nickname which omits an initial "Mo" (5) - NIQUE - EQUIN_*
 32. According to his family members, dictator in India being accompanied by European princess (3) - IDI - I + DI
 35. Old English character's initially all right to leave our home (3) - ETH - E(-a_ r_)TH
 36. Coming up: You have a sit-down with the Finnish Flash (5) - TEEMU - (U + MEET)<
 37. AC/DC cover not included on studio's initial records (3, abbr.) - CDS - _C/D_ + S_
 38. Richard watched Jurassic Park, finally; I joined partway through (4) - DICK - _D _C _K; I joined partway through
 39. Unpredictable son of President Trump catches traitor (7) - ERRATIC - ERIC catches RAT
 40. Those with little interest in others: Check it out, old hat with mostly new clothes in restaurants! (6) - LONERS - LO + NE_ + R_S
 41. Made attempts to ogle; in the end decided to grab butt from behind (7) - ESSAYED - EYE + _D to grab ASS<
 42. He no longer seeks parts as someone engaged in extortion (7) - EXACTOR - ddef (EX-ACTOR)
 44. Shows | a lack of necessities (5) - NEEDS - ddef
 45. Every now and then, stars perform very well, making splash (5) - TRACE - _T_R_ + ACE
 47. Evidence described by company department: Female couple in Hook up (5) - PROOF - PR + (F + _OO_)<
 48. Thoroughfares for passenger vehicles lacking parking (5) - LANES - (-p)LANES
 49. Popular choice of where to meet in The Post-covid era is where to see caged beasts and men (4) - ZOOM - ZOO + M
 51. Marcellus's girlfriend is nowhere to be found (3) - MIA - ddef


Oof, big one to be sniped on! Well done :) +1

@Stiv ha, I was sure someone was gonna beat me to the punch! good to know that wasn't just paranoia ;P
